# Visual Studio Build statistics

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation

I'm interested in how much time I am spending on building my projects every day. Is there any existing tool which provides such statistics?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "how much time spent on building.."? Do you mean from the time you started clicking "build" to the time it completed (regardlesssuccessful or not)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MSBuild (what VisualStudio uses to build) can provide you with this information. Include in your msbuild.exe call the [PerformanceSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) switch:

```
msbuild.exe your.sln /clp:PerformanceSummary ...
```

That will give you something like this at the end of your build run log:

```
Project Performance Summary:
      374 ms  your.sln  1 calls

Target Performance Summary:
...
      109 ms  GetWinFXPath                               1 calls
      156 ms  EntityDeploy                               1 calls
      390 ms  Build                                      2 calls
...
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43
```

If you want a file that contains only this information, rather than having it written to your console, you can use this switch (with logfile set to some path):

```
/logger:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=perf.log;encoding=Unicode;performancesummary
```

Comment: Great answer!
Is there anyway to change the msbuild.exe parameters in the visual studio IDE? 

I suppose I could replace the original msbuild.exe with a script which runs the original msbuild.exe with some parameters, but there must be a cleaner way?

Comment: Found the answer myself.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is build event, you can use them, you can also run a batch script before and after a build to echo time >> filename

and then render the file and get your stats.

(goto build events in the project property page)

Comment: I know I can script it, I was asking if there is an *existing* tool/script which I can use, preferrably integrated into the IDE...

Comment: I guess one can write a build task and plug it in to the environment, but I don't know about one that calculates build times.
I'll look around, codeproject might have something.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use continuous integration tools like Cruise or Cruise.NET, these tools do a very good job of showing metrics like build times, average build times etc.

Comment: This would actually defeat the purpose since I am interested in how much *interactive* time goes to waste - that is, builds I perform manually to test changes in the code.

I don't really know Cruise Control though so perhaps I am missing some of its capabilities.